# How to implement this recursion relation?

Tags: functions, recursion, variable-definitions

I am trying to implement the following relation in Mathematica for any $k$:

$$\begin{align} t_{n,n_1, \ldots, n_k} &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=0}^{n-2} \left( t_{m,n-m-2,n_1, \ldots, n_k} - \frac{1}{N} t_{n-2,n_1,\ldots,n_k} \right) + \frac{n_1}{2} \left( t_{n+n_1-2,n_2,\ldots,n_k} - \frac{1}{N} t_{n-1,n_1-1,n_2,\ldots,n_k} \right) \\ & \qquad\qquad\qquad + \ldots + \frac{n_k}{2} \left( t_{n+n_k-2,n_1,\ldots,n_{k-1}} - \frac{1}{N} t_{n-1,n_k-1,n_2,\ldots,n_{k-1}} \right)\,. \tag{1} \end{align}$$

The start values are:

$$t_0 = N\,, \qquad t_1 = 0\,, \qquad t_2 = \frac{N^2-1}{2}\,, \tag{2}$$

and note that the indices are not ordered.

The first term is easy and can be implemented with something of the type:

```
t[n_, nk___] := 1/2 Sum[t[m, n - m - 2, nk] - 1/N t[n - 2, nk], {m, 0, n - 2}]
```

But I am struggling with the other terms, since the indices do not appear as a group together. I can always write the relation up to a given $k$, but is it possible to generalise to any $k$, and if yes how?

*Small extra question*: I know I am not supposed to use `N` as a variable, but I am so used to it and it always works. Would it be possible to use `Nc` instead, but have it displayed as `N`? This exists for example in the FeynCalc package, where the variable `SUNN` is displayed as `N`.

Comment: To display `Nc` as `N` you can use `Format[Nc]:=N`

Comment: @Hausdorff `MakeBoxes[Nc, StandardForm] := InterpretationBox["N", Nc]` is probably a better choice, because the output in the notebook will be interpreted correctly even if you edit/copy it.

Comment: @xzczd Oh, that is a much neater way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: $t_{n\color{red}{+}n_1-2,n_2,\ldots,n_k}$  <- Is it a typo?

Comment: @xzczd No that's how the recursion goes (it's eq. (2.30) in 1705.02909).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the relation you wrote is only valid for $n>2$. For $n=0,1,2$ you have to use the identities of eq.(2.31) in [1705.02909],
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
t_{0,n_1,n_2\dots} &= Nt_{n_1,n_2},\\
t_{1,n_1,n_2\dots} &= 0,\\
t_{2,n_1,n_2\dots} &= \frac{N^2-1+n_1+n_2+\dots}{2}t_{n_1,n_2,\dots}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The code below should do the trick, though more elegant solutions are definitely possible. You can check that it reproduces the sample values given in eq.(2.32) of the paper.

```
ClearAll[t]
t[0,nk__Integer] := Nc t[nk]
t[1,nk__Integer] := 0
t[2,nk__Integer] := 1/2(Nc^2-1+Plus@@{nk}) t[nk]

t[0] = Nc;
t[1] = 0;
t[2] = (Nc^2-1)/2;

t[n_Integer, nk___Integer] /; n>2 := t[n, nk] = 
    1/2 Sum[t[m, n - m - 2, nk] - 1/Nc   t[n - 2, nk], {m, 0, n-2}]+
    Sum[
        {nk}[[i]]/2(
            t[n+{nk}[[i]]-2,Sequence@@Delete[{nk},i]]-
            1/Nc t[n-1,Sequence@@ReplacePart[{nk},i->{nk}[[i]]-1]]
        ),
   {i,Length@{nk}}]
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! That helps me a lot to learn how to write such codes myself!